# Newtonsoft.Json not working on the iphone device work on emulator monotouch iphone

Tags: iphone, json, xamarin.ios

I create a build for my application and run on the device. While it is woking on the emulator but not working on the device. and cause this error:

```
  Exception in Class: BaseIOAddOn 
Line : 0 
and Method:ParseGeneralSettingsFromSettingJson 
with message Attempting to JIT compile method 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken:Value<int> (object)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
```

I'm using `json.NET 4.0 R3 for MonoTouch` for parsing json's but i do not know what is the issue that it is not yet working on device.

EDIT:
I have not any components folder in my application solution. I download the JSON.Net dll from the xamaring components site and replace it with my Newtonsoft.JSon.monotouhch.dll but yet it is not working.

I found the Components folder on the xamarin studio and add the component to the app from this folder but still I get the above error. I'm confiusing why it say error is in line 0.

In the exception in said line 0 but from erro content and my codes priority i think it is from this code:

```
try {
            Dictionary <string  ,string > generalSettings = new Dictionary <string ,string > ();
            JObject jsonUnits = JObject.Parse (Response);
            var settingsList = jsonUnits ["settings"] [SettingTypes .AppSettings.GetDescription ()];
            int i = 0;
            var tmp_factor = settingsList [i.ToString ()];
            while (tmp_factor!=null) {
                generalSettings  .Add (tmp_factor ["name"].ToString (), tmp_factor ["value"].ToString ());
                i++;
                tmp_factor = settingsList [i.ToString ()];
            }
            var addOnComplexStatus = jsonUnits["settings"][SettingTypes .GetAddon  .GetDescription ()].Value <int>("status");

            generalSettings .Add (AppConstants .XmlAddOnComplexKey.GetDescription() ,addOnComplexStatus .ToString ());

            return generalSettings;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Common .HandleException (ex);
            return null;
        }
```

especially:

```
var addOnComplexStatus = jsonUnits["settings"][SettingTypes .GetAddon  .GetDescription ()].Value <int>("status");
```

I found this article: http://www.brettnagy.com/post/2009/11/21/Using-JsonNET-with-MonoTouch.aspx that said using this code: `[MonoTouch.Foundation.Preserve]`
I do not understand it, what is this?

Comment: Have you tried the version of JSON.Net from the Xamarin component store? I have used this one across several apps without issue. You might post the code where the issue is occurring also.

Comment: No I don not know this.
My codes all is based on this file. is their syntax same?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same.

Comment: How can use this library and replace it with this dll?

Comment: I found also this links:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/pull/1544 -  https://github.com/gshackles/SignalR/commit/1208eb067ec2340adae7cfbd9b9d6763860e5438  -  https://github.com/gshackles/SignalR/blob/1208eb067ec2340adae7cfbd9b9d6763860e5438/lib/Newtonsoft.Json.MonoTouch.dll -  May their resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for helping.
When I changed this line of code:

```
var addOnComplexStatus = jsonUnits["settings"][SettingTypes .GetAddon  .GetDescription ()].Value <int>("status");
```

to this:

```
var addOnComplexStatus = jsonUnits["settings"][SettingTypes .GetAddon  .GetDescription ()]["status"].ToString ();
```

The problem resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the reference to Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the project, and if you have the source for the project -- remove it from the solution.  (Just don't delete it, in case this doesn't solve your problem)

In the "Components" folder, right click and choose "Add Component".  Search for JSON.Net and add the component.

Try with this pre-compiled DLL and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I use a refrence to Newtonsoft.Json.dll - i do not understand the meanin of "  (Just don't delete it, in case this doesn't solve your problem) ".

Comment: Also i can not find the component folder, :(

Comment: I double click on the refrence folder and tried to find JSON.Net but I could not. there is a system.json but no JSON.net

Comment: Ow, jonathan please help me

Comment: What version of Xamarin Studio/MonoTouch are you using?

Comment: xamarin studio version 4.0.3 - I update it last night from monodevelop to xamarin studio. also ios 6.2.3

Comment: I now again check it for updates and every thing was updated to last stable version

Comment: I see also the sample projects that I download from xamarin samples but no one have not components folder :( . This is the deadline of my project and I yet is chalenging with this :(

Comment: I download this component from http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/json.net - it have two dll in its lib folder but their name is ye newtonsot,Json.dll should i replace my past refrence with this?

Comment: Sure, try it.  I am not sure why your components aren't showing up. This is a MonoTouch project, right?

Comment: Yes this is a monotouch project

Comment: I add the component from the component folder but yet the problem not resolve :(